# Best database for Geographical database for my case

Tags: database, google-cloud

I'd like help to make a decision on database change.

For now my case is:

MySQL on Cloud SQL (GCP): Storing GPS Tracking Data for now is 400Million Record (Around 400GB). And going bigger every day. For now is quite slow to processing the report like routing report, trip report

I have plan to move all of these to Google Cloud Datastore.

Is this is a good case for my situation to move to Google Cloud Datastore?
The reason why i'm choosing Google Cloud Datastore is:
Easy Scaling, Faster query.

But i had wondering that Google Cloud Datastore can write only 1 operation/second. I need to write the GPS Tracking every second for more than 10K Device

(I'm sure that i'm not understand this clear so can anyone explain me about transaction or the way can write more entity per second)

Does anyone have anything to recommend to let me know the best solution?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model works. Questions soliciting opinions for the "best" of anything are usually closed. It seems ss if your research into options was flawed if the only option you're considering is documented as not meeting your requirements. You have a kernel of a non-subjective question here, but this Question needs to be edited to bring that question to the fore.